# Google Chrome background jittering when moving pictures

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, background-image

I was working on an image gallery and it involved some heavy image moving\resizing using javascript. Everything worked like a charm on all the broswers except for IE6\7 (no wonder) and ... Google Chrome. 
Basically under certain zooming each movement made Chrome redraw the background, making it jitter, change its position and then move back. I can't post link to the actual script at the moment, but I used a jquery plugin to immitate the problem: 
http://danilsk.narod.ru/wtf.html (try zooming in and out and clicking images) 
Does anyone know how to fight this?

Answer (score 0):

I am using google chrome and I see no issue here.

Everything is running very smoothly. Try updating your browser.

FYI:
Ubuntu 10.04 LTS - the Lucid Lynx

Google Chrome 8.0.552.215